# Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'none'" fonts.gstatic.com

Tags: content-security-policy

In my CSP i have added

```
 font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com;
```

I am getting the generic error

> Refused to load the font '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'none'"

And the specific error

> Refused to load the font 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/mulish/v10/1Ptvg83HX_SGhgqk0gotYKNnBcif.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'none'".

When I do this:

```
font-src 'none' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
```

I get this error:

> The Content-Security-Policy directive 'font-src' contains the keyword 'none' alongside with other source expressions. The keyword 'none' must be the only source expression in the directive value, otherwise it is ignored.

And when I do this:

```
font-src 'none';
```

I get this error:

> Refused to load the font 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/mulish/v10/1Ptvg83HX_SGhgqk0gotYKNnBcif.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'none'"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you have multiple CSPs defined. The image needs to pass the img-src directive (or the default-src fallback) for all CSPs present. They could be in response headers or in meta tags.

You will need to identify the CSPs and modify/remove what you don't need.

Comment: This font is being loaded from origin js.stripe.com. Does this somehow contain its own CSP that conflicting with mine?

Comment: You will need to check where the violation is triggered and the corresponding CSP. Check the headers of responses with content (typically text/html).

Comment: @Matt has anyone solved it? me too is in in stripe's js file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with something like this in your case

```
font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com;
```